# Detection ROI using openCV

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm doing a work where I have to find the region of interest (ROI) and then perform a threshold on the image:

[image]

As I am not from the field of computing, I'm having some difficulties.

I started trying to find the ROI through the following code:

```
// code
string filename = "2011-06-11-09%3A12%3A15.387932.bmp";

Mat img = imread(filename)

if (!img.data)
{
    std::cout << "!!! imread não conseguiu abrir imagem: " << filename << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

cv::Rect roi;
roi.x = 0
roi.y = 90

roi.width = 400;
roi.height = 90;

cv::Mat crop = original_image(roi); 
cv::imwrite("2011-06-11-09%3A12%3A15.387932.bmp", crop);
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

I assume that you are interested in isolating the digits of the image and that you want to specify the ROI manually (given what you wrote).

You can [**use better coordinates for the ROI** and crop that into a new `cv::Mat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13533305/176769) with it to get something like the output below:

[image]

Executing a threshold on this image only makes sense if you want to isolate the digits to do some recognition later. A good technique for doing that is offered by [`cv::inRange()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7959488/176769) which performs a threshold operation on all channels (RGB image == 3 channels).

**Note**: `cv::Mat` stores pixels in the BGR order, this is important to remember when you specify the values for the threshold.

As a simple test, you can perform a threshold **from B:70 G:90 R:100 to B:140 G:140 R:140** to get the following output:

[image]

Not bad! I changed your code a little to get these results:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("input.jpg");
    if (!image.data)
    {
        std::cout << "!!! imread failed to load image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Rect roi;
    roi.x = 165;
    roi.y = 50;
    roi.width = 440;
    roi.height = 80;

    /* Crop the original image to the defined ROI */

    cv::Mat crop = image(roi);
    cv::imwrite("colors_roi.png", crop);

    /* Threshold the ROI based on a BGR color range to isolate yellow-ish colors */

    cv::Mat dest;
    cv::inRange(crop, cv::Scalar(70, 90, 100), cv::Scalar(140, 140, 140), dest);
    cv::imwrite("colors_threshold.png", dest);

    cv::imshow("Example", dest);    
    cv::waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```